# Is there a library version of SQL Azure Migration Wizard?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I am looking for a way to backup/export my data from Sql Azure onto a local computer.
I would like to integrate it into my existing program.

I know there is now the DAC framework. However it still seems to have its own issues so I'd like to hold off on it in the mean time.

The [Sql Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) seems to do everything I need and does it pretty well.

- Copy data Structure to a plain SQL file
- Copy all of the data with BCP

However the architecture is tightly coupled to Windows Forms and the separation of concerns is confusing and there seams to be duplication of code between the BatchExport project and WizardProject because basic functionality is mixed presentation code.

Has anyone created something similar that can be used as a library? Or created a branch off that project with the functionality separated from the presentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enzo Backup has a reasonable price and you can test a trial version: [Enzo Backup Information](http://www.bluesyntax.net/backup.aspx)